# Struggling to understand why "Capturing by reference ensures that runningTotal and amount do not disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends'?

Tags: ios, swift, reference, closures, capture

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of Capturing Values. I saw this from "The Swift Programming Language 2.1":

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}

let incrementByTen = makeIncrement(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen()
```

> “The incrementer() function doesn’t have any parameters, and yet it
>   refers to runningTotal and amount from within its function body. It
>   does this by capturing a reference to runningTotal and amount from the
>   surrounding function and using them within its own function body.
>   Capturing by reference ensures that runningTotal and amount do not
>   disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends, and also ensures that
>   runningTotal is available the next time the incrementer function is
>   called.”

Forgive me if the questions I am about to ask sounds simple or silly to some of you, but its been troubling me a lot.

Q1. Why "capture by reference can ensure that runningTotal and amount do not disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends"?

Q2. Why "capture by reference can ensure that runningTotal is available the next time the incrementer function is called"?

I'm finding it very difficult to picture and to make sense of those statements in my mind. Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift automatically does memory management through [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) (Automatic Reference Counting). At a high level, when a (strong) reference is created against something, a counter increases. The object won't be released from memory if the reference counter is above 0.

So, by creating a reference (which happens when you capture the values from the parent function) you're making sure that the memory isn't deallocated.

Comment: `runningTotal` is an `Int` which is a *value type* and not subject to reference counting. ARC is only done for *reference types* (i.e. instances of a class).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong Martin, but *functions* are also a reference types. (according to the section in the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) documentation titled "Closures are reference types", combined with the fact that functions are special cases of closures). I haven't found a good resource on this yet but it appears that the nested function is 'closing' over the parent function's values via a reference to the parent function itself.

Comment: That is correct, and perhaps I misunderstood your answer (and I apologize in that case!) – you don't state explicitly *what* is reference counted. The question (as I understand it) was what keeps the `runningTotal` variable alive.

Comment: Yeah - I didn't want to put it in my answer because I don't know for certain what the reference is to - The guide on closures says *"Swift also handles all memory management involved in disposing of variables when they are no longer needed."* which implies ARC. Just because we as swift programmers can't pass an `Int` as a reference, it doesn't mean the compiler can't and for all I know that could be happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

As [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) says:

```
Calling the function multiple times shows this behavior in action:
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 10
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 20
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 30
```

**Q1**. Why "capture by reference can ensure that runningTotal and amount do not disappear when the call to makeIncrementer ends"?

**A1**. Every time you call `incrementByTen`, a call to `makeIncrementer` ends. But still the value of `runningTotal` does not disappear and you can see this in the output.

**Q2**. Why "capture by reference can ensure that runningTotal is available the next time the incrementer function is called"?

**A2**. Every time you call `incrementByTen`, `incrementer` is called. Everytime `incrementer` is called via `incrementByTen`, you have the modified value of `runningTotal`. This also can be seen from the output.